# Different mysql join query based on user level

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, left-join

I'm seeking an idea or best practice to perform the below:

I have the tables:
`profile` contains basic info (id, email, pass, lvl)
`profile_user` contains (pid, name, age, etc..)
`profile_mod` contains (pid, company_name, money, etc..)

as you can see that I will do left join on two tables to get the whole information, but the join will be all based on the attribute lvl. If lvl=1 it will leftjoin on profile_user and lvl=2 will perform join on profile_mod.

My question is, I don't want to perform a check on every query to get the lvl and then do the leftjoin on the other two tables. I was wondering if there is a best practice for such case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT    *
FROM      profile a
LEFT JOIN profile_user b ON a.id = b.pid AND a.lvl = 1
LEFT JOIN profile_mod  c ON a.id = c.pid AND a.lvl = 2
```

If `lvl` is `1`, values for fields in `profile_user` will populate, and values in `profile_mod` will be `NULL`.

Likewise, if `lvl` is `2`, values for fields in `profile_user` will be `NULL`, but values in `profile_mod` will be populated.

Comment: how i can automatically omit the selected attributes rather than having them as NULL values?